# To-do list for Google Calendar: tasks with no due date

Tags: google-calendar, calendar, tasks

I'd like to manage a to-do list using Google Calendar.  I can see how to create tasks in Google Calendar.  However, each task is forced to have a due date.  It appears that the due date always shows up as today.  The task doesn't automatically roll over to tomorrow if I don't mark it as finished.

I'd like to be able to create a task with no due date, so that it'll appear on my to-do list forever until I delete it or tick a checkbox to indicate that it's done.  Is there a way to do this in Google Calendar?  Is there a way to create tasks with no due date?  Or, is there an easy way to create a task with a due date very far in the future, and have it appear on a daily task list until it is done?

(I don't use Gmail, ideally I'd prefer to be able to create and view tasks from within Google Calendar, but I'll take whatever I can get.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this.  Look for "My calendars" on the left.  Click it to expand it.  You should see a row/item labelled "Tasks".  If the checkbox next to "Tasks" is not already checked, check it.  Now you should see a sidebar on the right appear, labelled "Tasks".  This is the list of tasks.  Click any empty area in that sidebar, and that will let you create a new task.  The key step was to enable "Tasks" under "My calendars", otherwise it's difficult to figure out how to create a new task.

My thanks to Stuart for a hint that was useful in helping me to figure this out.

---

Here are some web-based alternatives:

- [Remember the Milk](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/)
- [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/)
- [hiTask](http://hitask.com/)

Toodledo has [a comparison chart](http://www.toodledo.com/info/compare.php) comparing a bunch of web-based services.

Answer (score 1):

Create the task in the task area on the right-hand-side of the page.

You don't need to specify a date, it will only appear in the task block, not on the calendar.